# Divs in one line with overflowed parent

Tags: html, css, overflow

Having one parent div with width:70px and overflow-x:hidden I want to add 2 children div with width:50px in one line, such that a second div will has 20px of visible part, and 30px hidden by parent node. Here what I tried to do:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    width:70px;
    height:50px;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
#first{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#aeaeae;
    display:inline-block;
}
#second{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CC0A0A;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the `#parent` so that inline-level children do not wrap to a new line.

Also note that there's a whitespace between inline-level elements in inline flow, you could remove that by:

- removing spaces/tabs/newlines in the markup `...</div><div>...`.
- Commenting the spaces/tabs/newlines in the markup `<!-- -->`.
- Setting the `font-size` of the parent to `0` and re-setting it back to `16px` on children
- and...

```css
#parent{
  width:70px;
  height:50px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#first{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#aeaeae;
  display:inline-block;
}

#second{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#CC0A0A;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="first">First element</div><div id="second">Second element</div>
</div>
```